# Wiedemann–Franz law for Copper at 100 °C

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, material-science, semiconductor-physics, thermal-conductivity

I have a colossal temperature (**T**)-dependent expression which has both the thermal conductivity (**κ**) and the electrical conductivity (**σ**) of copper. **T** fluctuates around 100$\pm$10 °C.

For simplification, I' want to get rid of κ. While I'll run my own experiments to check the accuracy, I'm wondering if it is safe to use Wiedemann–Franz law with a good confidence about precision?

$$\frac{κ}{σ}=LT$$

where $L=\frac{\pi^2}{3}(\frac{k_B}{e})^2$ is the Lorenz number.

Any other compact model is also appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer this for you. You can presumably compare the full expression and the one substituting for $\kappa$ and see if the differences fall within what you regard as acceptable limits. It's not obvious what we could add to this.

Comment: @JohnRennie Wiedemann–Franz law is claimed to be true by itself regardless of expression. So you do not need to know the expression. The question is, if the law (approximation) is good enough within the given temperature for copper or not.

Comment: I don't understand the tag for semiconductor-physics here. Since both electrical and thermal conductivity for copper are readily available in tabular form, it should be easy to check if it is acceptable for your particular problem.

Comment: @JonCuster Can you show me one?